# Find Text By Nth Class Name is Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I would like to get the the Date time text on this webpage but had issues locating it. A help will be appreciated.

If I use this codde,
var = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-md-3'))).text

I get the text in the first class (col-md-39). How do a I get the text in third class in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the locator to get the desired result:

```
By.XPath, '//*[text()="Last communication"]//parent::div'
```

Comment: A little modification worked for me.    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-md-3'][.//strong[text()='Last communication']]"))).text.splitlines()[-1]

Comment: @user16794957 _`wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-md-3'][.//strong[text()='Last communication']]"))).text.splitlines()[-1]`_ wasn't that exactly my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75323636/7429447) ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Your answer really helped me and I appreciated that. I tried using the "getattributes" in your answer which was throwing an error. All I did was to  remove that and introduce "text" and post it back thinking it might help others. I used 99.9% of your response.

Comment: The difference between `get_attribute()` and `text` is almost nil, atleast for Selenium beginers :) anyways, good luck

Answer (score 0):

The *Date Time* text is within a text node. So to print the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH* and *childNodes[n]*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-md-3'][.//strong[text()='Last communication']]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-md-3'][.//strong[text()='Last communication']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[-1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```